# Need multiple allowed users in Elmah/Mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, elmah

I've recently set up Elmah in a mvc project. I need the Elmah log to be seen by 2 or 3 different admin users.

Is there anyway to do something like this?

```
  <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="user1,user2,user3" />
```

PD: I have all the users in different roles, so i can't use roles :(

Comment: Sorry. Just noticed that you are using Elmah.MVC. I wrote another tutorial that might help you: [ELMAH security and allowRemoteAccess explained](http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-security-and-allowremoteaccess-explained/). But yes you can specify multiple users through that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELMAH supports access authorization through standard [URL Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd(v=vs.100).aspx). Check out this article for help:

https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages

I also wrote an entire [ELMAH tutorial](http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-tutorial/) which shows how to secure ELMAH logs.

As an example, you would have to write something like this:

```
<location path="elmah.axd">  
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" 
                 path="elmah.axd" 
                 type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="kristonpelz" />  
            <deny users="*" /> 
        </authorization>  
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="ELMAH" 
                 verb="POST,GET,HEAD"
                 path="elmah.axd" 
                 type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"
                 preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add multiple Rows for each user EG

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="user1" />  
    <allow users="user2" />  
    <deny users="*" />  
</authorization>
```